# Detect double free in C++ code

Tags: c++

I have a code,

```
class foo
{
   public:
     foo(){};
     ~foo(){};
};

class bar
{
   public:
      bar(){};
     ~bar(){};

      foo& Foo()
      {
         return m_foo;
      }

  private:
      foo m_foo; 
};

int main()
{
   bar *obj = new bar;

   if( /* true condition here */ )
   {
      foo lcFoo;
      lcFoo = obj->Foo(); // forgot this
   }

   delete obj;
}
```

Now I am getting a double free message from glibc when I call the "delete obj" part.

Please advice.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Thanks for the comments but this is the exact code I used. Do you think the problem is in the foo& Foo() function because it return the reference of the m_foo object and then when code jump to the if condition brace then that m_foo will be deleted?

Comment: Please post more code. There isn't much to see here.

Comment: It's good to reduce the problem to a simple piece of code, but there's simply no double-free in what you posted.

Comment: You might try running your code under valgrind, it can often point out what is going wrong.

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you please clarify what the problem is? Your code is missing a lot of important info.

Comment: There's something missing in this picture.

Comment: Is `lcFoo = Foo();` really `lcFoo = obj->Foo();` ?

Comment: This: "foo lcFoo; lcFoo = obj->Foo();" probably isn't want you want anyhow. It will actually cause a copy of Bar's Foo. Perhaps you want "foo& lcFoo = obj->Foo();".

Comment: "...but this is the exact code I used". This exact code cannot possibly result in double free. If you are getting a double free, you are most certainly using a different code.

Comment: There is no reason to detect. It will show up. The question would have been more meaningful if it was 'how to I prevent .....'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no double free in the code you posted. I suspect that there is some pointer resource in `foo`, which is being copied as a pointer when foo is copied; yet is `delete`d in `foo`'s destructor.

You might also want to change the contents of your `if` block to

```
foo& lcFoo = obj->Foo();
```

though the fact that you're getting double frees here is indicative of larger issues than this.

Answer (score 4):

Your `foo` class has not implemented the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) properly: every time you implement a destructor, it is usually an indication that you *also* need a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

My guess is that you've got some pointer in the `foo` class that you're `delete`ing in `foo`'s destructor, but since you're not implementing a copy constructor when you copy the `foo` class, it's just copying the pointer. When both instances of `foo` are destructed, they each try to `free` that pointer, and get the error.

However, rather than implementing a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, I would suggest you get rid of the destructor in `foo` and use a smart pointer (`shared_ptr` probably) instead.

As others have already pointed out, you probably also want to say `foo &lcFoo = obj->Foo()` but **that's only going to hide the bigger problem**.

Comment: Use smart ptr instead of _what_ ? It only lets you to forget about `delete` ing, but does not replace destructor. I think you wanted to say `get rid of the delete` ?

Comment: I thought you don't need to impl any of the Three, when class is so simple, that you can just memcpy its instances

Comment: @Alexander: No, what he's posted is correct. The destructor is called as part of `delete`. +1 to this answer for indicating more specifically I meant by "larger issues than this" in my above answer.

Comment: @Billy I agree with him, but I just wanted to point out, that wording is confusing. Smart ptr can replace destructor only if object contains ptr, which isn't true in general case => hence confusion

Comment: @Alexander: Isn't that covered by "My guess is that you've got some pointer in the `foo` class" ?

Comment: @Billy: emmm... Now I finally see the point of yours and this answer, +1. A bit retarded at morning. Thanks for patience :)

Comment: Sorry @Alexander, yes @Billy is correct, I meant use a `smart_ptr` for the pointer that *I'm guessing* is contained in `foo`, rather than deleting it in `foo`'s destructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your code through [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) if you are using Linux.